# Rails 3.2.11: Weird behaviour because of loading order of Controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am migrating an old Rails application to Rails 3.2.11/Ruby 1.9.3.

We have an `ActiveRecord` model `ControlPoint` that inherits from another model `EventDependent`. When `ControlPoint` gets loaded, it calls a method of `EventDependent` to set the `table_name`, and for this it needs an "Event id" (Each event has its own database).

The key of all this, is that we need to know the "Event id" when the model gets loaded.

The `control_point_controller` has a `before_filter` to call a controller method that gets the needed "Event id" (via params). In the previous version of Rails, this always worked fine.

But with Rails 3.2.11 it works sometimes... and sometimes it does not!

When it does not work, the problem is that the "set table name" of the model gets called before we have the "Event id" ready. I have tried to debug it with the debugger, but many times, the flow does not enter in the before_filter action, as it fails before that. Other times it enters... and when it does, we have params available, and it all works fine.

I have been searching about this, but could not find anything specific that is related. I would say that the problem is that the loading order for model and controller is not fixed... and they start loading at the same time and sometimes one gets loaded before the other. Does this make sense ? I think that around 70% of times it does not work, because there is not "event id" defined yet (because it did not execute the before_filter and params did not exist yet), and the other 30% of times it does.

My question is: Could I somehow delay the load of the model ? Or make it load after the before_filter of the controller ? Any other idea of what the problem may be ?

I can post relevant code if you wish so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this and wanted to share it with you, in case someone has a similar problem, or want to suggest better ideas.

as I said, the problem was that I had no control over when the "set_table_name" was executed in the model, as this call was just "floating" in the model, like this:

```
class ControlPoint < EventDependentModel
    set_table_name 'ControlPoints'
    ....
    ....
end
```

So when this got called before the `before_filter` of the controller (it happened some times, randomly...), the "event_id" was not available yet.

What I did, was to remove that call to `set_table_name` from the model, and add another `before_filter` in the `control_point_controller` like this:

```
class ControlPointsController < EventDependentController
    before_filter :prepare_table_name
    .....
    .....

    protected
       def prepare_table_name
           ControlPoint.set_table_name 'ControlPoints'
       end
end
```

There is another `before_filter` in `EventDependentController`, which sets the "event_id" that we need (via params).This way, when `set_table_name` will be executed (before every action in my controller), the "event_id" has already been set by the other before_filter in the parent controller.

Regards !